# How to keep a slice of a numpy array and clear the rest from memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a list which contains several large `numpy arrays`

I want to only keep a slice of each of those arrays, and clear my system memory. I have tried using the keywords `del` and `None` but those do not seem to have any effect (I use the fedora system monitor to monitor RAM usage).

The issue is that I want to save my slices using `numpy.save()` but I run out of memory, hence my question.

For example I have:

```
my_list = [arr0, arr1, arr2]
```

And I would like to end up with:

```
my_list = [arr0[10:100], arr1[10:100], arr2[10:100]]
```

So I have tried to do

```
arr_tmp = np.copy(arr0[10:100])
my_list[0] = arr_tmp
arr0 = None
```

and

```
arr_tmp = np.copy(arr0[10:100])
my_list[0] = arr_tmp
del arr0
```

but none of those seems to work.

EDIT : I run out of memory when using the `numpy.save()` function, not when slicing my array. I want to free some memory before calling `numpy.save()` so it does not get killed by the system.

Comment: Are all those arrays of the same shape?

Comment: yes they have the same shape

Comment: Can you initialize an output array with a shape of `(N_arrs,91)` and fill into it iteratively from arr0,arr1, etc.? I am assuming you are running out of memory to create `my_list` with : `my_list = [arr0[10:100], arr1[10:100], arr2[10:100]]`.

Comment: I run out of memory when I use `numpy.save(my_list)`, so I want to free some memory before calling that one

Comment: So, maybe with a NumPy array instead of a list as suggested earlier you might avoid the memory error? Worth a try I would say.

Comment: What happens when you do `np.array(my_list)`?  The first thing `np.save` does with your list is pass it through `np.asanyarray(obj)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by transposing the list twice: `my_list.transpose()[10:100].transpose()`

```
arr1=[0,1,2,3,4]
arr2=[0,1,2,3,4]
arr3=[0,1,2,3,4]
my_list=np.array([arr1,arr2,arr3])
my_list.transpose()[1:4].transpose()
```

returns:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

If you save this in a new value you should be able to just delete the old array.

You can then trigger the garbage collection to remove unreference values with the `gc` package (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html)):

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

Comment: How do I delete the old array ? assigning it to `None` or using `del` does not seem to work

Comment: @jmatthieu I've updated my answer to include garbage collection with `gc.collect()`

Answer (score 0):

You can add zero to the slice:

`smallSlice = bigArray[...,::10]`

`del bigArray`

will leave bigArray in memory, as there is a copy the slice points to.

`smallSlice = bigArray[...,::10] + 0`

`del bigArray`

will create a new array, and bigArray will be deleted.